# Oracle Client throws ArgumentException with ulong parameter

Tags: oracle, oracleclient, odac, argumentexception, ulong

I need to insert a `ulong` (i.e., `UInt64`) number into an Oracle database, but am running into an `ArgumentException`. I'm inserting it into a `NUMBER` column, which I have assured myself should be able to store any number from 0 to 2^64-1.

Here is a minimal example that will reproduce the error:

```
// First create the following table:
//
//     CREATE TABLE SampleTable (SampleColumn NUMBER)
//
using (var dbConnection = new OracleConnection("..."))
{
    ulong valueToInsert = 123;

    OracleCommand command = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO SampleTable (SampleColumn) VALUES (:SampleColumn)";
    command.Parameters.Add("SampleColumn", valueToInsert);

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This code works just fine if `valueToInsert` is of any other integer type (including `long`), but when I try it with `ulong`, I get the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  Source=Oracle.DataAccess
  StackTrace:
     at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter..ctor(String parameterName, Object obj)
     at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection.Add(String name, Object val)
```

Why is this happening?

P.S. I have tried using both Oracle.DataAccess 2.112.1.2 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.212.1.0.

Comment: Please show the table schema declaration.

Comment: It is given in the C# comment, but here it is: `CREATE TABLE SampleTable (SampleColumn NUMBER)`

Comment: What if you explicitly set the data type on the Parameters call?

Comment: Hmm it seems you are on to something; it appears there is no OracleDbType.UInt64, only OracleDbType.Int64. I'm not sure which OracleDbType would be appropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different C# types are allowed to map to different `OracleDbType`s; a good listing is shown in an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334574/c-sharp-datatypes-oracle-datatypes).

It turns out there is no `OracleDbType.UInt64`, though I can not explain why.  Anyway, my problem can be solved by converting the argument to a `decimal` type before inserting:

```
command.Parameters.Add("SampleColumn", (decimal)(valueToInsert));
```

This allows it to become `OracleDbType.Decimal`, which any `ulong` number is convertible to.